# Is it better to use Canvas rather than addView dynamically in this scenario?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

I'm new to android development so I have this novice question here:

I have a Canvas View, customized, in an activity. I want to programmatically display images (PNG drawables).

Clearly I have 2 ways of doing this, the first, more conventional way is:

Option I:

1. Find the "Activity Layout" (the layout for the entire activity)
2. Set params for the PNG ImageView.
3. ActivityLayout.addView(pngImageView)

Edit: So this way, the PNG will be shown, but not really "a part of" the Canvas, as it is not really drawn "in" the Canvas, but on top of it but to users, it's impossible to tell.

Option II:

Use a Drawable object, set its resource to my desired PNG drawable, then call

```
Drawable.draw(myCanvas)
```

Edit: In this way, the drawable will be "a part of" the Canvas and actually drawn "in" it. But then again, the users wouldn't be able to tell it from the first option.

Would I be better off with Option II? Particularly, I want to manipulate the png drawable, flip it, rotate it etc. probably using Matrix.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I want as little hassle as possible, and I want to be able to export the entire canvas to bmp file in the future including everything on the canvas and the png drawable.

Comment: Hi this is quite weird, I always thought canvas - since it is born to tackle complicated computer graphics - should be more handy when it comes to complicated graphic manipulation? Could you be more kind as to tell me why a View is better if I "want to do something more complex"?

Answer (score 0):

The differences is that the canvas drawing is done by hardware acceleration (GPU), and the Dynamic drawing is done by software (CPU). If you disable hardware acceleration, they become the exact same.I am not sure which one is the more accurate, they seem like just different implementations.